# Why am i getting the income and expense name as undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When I enter any name in the description box of my income/expense, it gets added to the user interface but displays "undefined" instead of the description that was added. For example, if I enter "salary" then it will show "undefined". I am just a beginner and learning Web development. Please help me.
My HTML and JavaScript codes are as follows-

```js
var budgetController = (function() {

  var Expense = function(id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.decription = description;
    this.value = value;
  };

  var Income = function(id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.decription = description;
    this.value = value;
  };

  var data = {
    allItems: {
      exp: [],
      inc: []
    },

    total: {
      exp: 0,
      inc: 0
    }
  };

  return {
    addItems: function(type, des, val) {
      var newItem, ID;

      if (data.allItems[type].length > 0) {
        ID = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 1;
      } else {
        ID = 0;
      }


      if (type === 'exp') {
        newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val);
      } else if (type === 'inc') {
        newItem = new Income(ID, des, val);
      }

      data.allItems[type].push(newItem);
      return newItem;
    },

    //testing purpose
    testing: function() {
      console.log(data);
    }
  };

})();


//UI CONTROLLER

var UIController = (function() {

  var DOMstrings = {
    inputType: '.add__type',
    inputDescription: '.add__description',
    inputValue: '.add__value',
    inputButton: '.add__btn',
    incomeContainer: '.income__list',
    expensesContainer: '.expenses__list',
  };

  return {

    getInput: function() {
      return {
        type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value, // inc or exp
        decription: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDescription).value,
        value: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value
      };
    },

    addListitem: function(obj, type) {
      var html, newHtml, element;

      //create HTML string with placeholder text

      if (type === 'inc') {

        element = DOMstrings.incomeContainer;

        html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="income-%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
      } else if (type === 'exp') {

        element = DOMstrings.expensesContainer;

        html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="expense-%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__percentage">21%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
      }

      //replace placeholder text with some actual data  

      newHtml = html.replace('%id%', obj.id);
      newHtml = newHtml.replace('%description%', obj.decription);
      newHtml = newHtml.replace('%value%', obj.value);

      //insert the HTML into DOM

      document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml);

    },

    getDOMstrings: function() {
      return DOMstrings;
    }
  };
})();


//CONTROLLER

var controller = (function(budgetCtrl, UICtrl) {

  var setupEventListeners = function() {

    var DOM = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();

    document.querySelector(DOM.inputButton).addEventListener('click', ctrlAddItem);
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
        ctrlAddItem();
      }
    });
  };

  var ctrlAddItem = function() {
    var input, newItem;

    //get the field input data
    input = UICtrl.getInput();

    //add the item to the budget controller
    newItem = budgetCtrl.addItems(input.type, input.description, input.value);

    //add the item to UI
    UICtrl.addListitem(newItem, input.type);

    //calculate the budget

    //display budget on UI

  };

  return {

    init: function() {

      //testing purpose
      console.log('hello');
      setupEventListeners();
    }
  };
})(budgetController, UIController);

controller.init();
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body>

  <div class="top">
    <div class="budget">
      <div class="budget__title">
        Available Budget in <span class="budget__title--month">%Month%</span>:
      </div>

      <div class="budget__value">+ 2,345.64</div>

      <div class="budget__income clearfix">
        <div class="budget__income--text">Income</div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="budget__income--value">+ 4,300.00</div>
          <div class="budget__income--percentage">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="budget__expenses clearfix">
        <div class="budget__expenses--text">Expenses</div>
        <div class="right clearfix">
          <div class="budget__expenses--value">- 1,954.36</div>
          <div class="budget__expenses--percentage">45%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="add">
      <div class="add__container">
        <select class="add__type">
          <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
          <option value="exp">-</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="add__description" placeholder="Add description">
        <input type="number" class="add__value" placeholder="Value">
        <button class="add__btn"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="income">
        <h2 class="income__title">Income</h2>

        <div class="income__list">

          <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Salary</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 2,100.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Sold car</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 1,500.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->

        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="expenses">
        <h2 class="expenses__title">Expenses</h2>

        <div class="expenses__list">

          <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Apartment rent</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 900.00</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">21%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Grocery shopping</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 435.28</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">10%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in:

```
getInput: function() {
      return {
        type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value, // inc or exp
        description: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDescription).value,
//________^ The s is missing
        value: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value
      };
},
```

You are mixing *description* and *decription*, be consistent

```js
var budgetController = (function() {

  var Expense = function(id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
  };

  var Income = function(id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
  };

  var data = {
    allItems: {
      exp: [],
      inc: []
    },

    total: {
      exp: 0,
      inc: 0
    }
  };

  return {
    addItems: function(type, des, val) {
      var newItem, ID;

      if (data.allItems[type].length > 0) {
        ID = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 1;
      } else {
        ID = 0;
      }


      if (type === 'exp') {
        newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val);
      } else if (type === 'inc') {
        newItem = new Income(ID, des, val);
      }

      data.allItems[type].push(newItem);
      return newItem;
    },

    //testing purpose
    testing: function() {
      console.log(data);
    }
  };

})();


//UI CONTROLLER

var UIController = (function() {

  var DOMstrings = {
    inputType: '.add__type',
    inputDescription: '.add__description',
    inputValue: '.add__value',
    inputButton: '.add__btn',
    incomeContainer: '.income__list',
    expensesContainer: '.expenses__list',
  };

  return {

    getInput: function() {
      return {
        type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value, // inc or exp
        description: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDescription).value,
        value: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value
      };
    },

    addListitem: function(obj, type) {
      var html, newHtml, element;

      //create HTML string with placeholder text

      if (type === 'inc') {

        element = DOMstrings.incomeContainer;

        html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="income-%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
      } else if (type === 'exp') {

        element = DOMstrings.expensesContainer;

        html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="expense-%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__percentage">21%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
      }

      //replace placeholder text with some actual data  

      newHtml = html.replace('%id%', obj.id);
      newHtml = newHtml.replace('%description%', obj.description);
      newHtml = newHtml.replace('%value%', obj.value);

      //insert the HTML into DOM

      document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml);

    },

    getDOMstrings: function() {
      return DOMstrings;
    }
  };
})();


//CONTROLLER

var controller = (function(budgetCtrl, UICtrl) {

  var setupEventListeners = function() {

    var DOM = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();

    document.querySelector(DOM.inputButton).addEventListener('click', ctrlAddItem);
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
        ctrlAddItem();
      }
    });
  };

  var ctrlAddItem = function() {
    var input, newItem;

    //get the field input data
    input = UICtrl.getInput();

    //add the item to the budget controller
    newItem = budgetCtrl.addItems(input.type, input.description, input.value);

    //add the item to UI
    UICtrl.addListitem(newItem, input.type);

    //calculate the budget

    //display budget on UI

  };

  return {

    init: function() {

      //testing purpose
      console.log('hello');
      setupEventListeners();
    }
  };
})(budgetController, UIController);

controller.init();
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body>

  <div class="top">
    <div class="budget">
      <div class="budget__title">
        Available Budget in <span class="budget__title--month">%Month%</span>:
      </div>

      <div class="budget__value">+ 2,345.64</div>

      <div class="budget__income clearfix">
        <div class="budget__income--text">Income</div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="budget__income--value">+ 4,300.00</div>
          <div class="budget__income--percentage">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="budget__expenses clearfix">
        <div class="budget__expenses--text">Expenses</div>
        <div class="right clearfix">
          <div class="budget__expenses--value">- 1,954.36</div>
          <div class="budget__expenses--percentage">45%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="add">
      <div class="add__container">
        <select class="add__type">
          <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
          <option value="exp">-</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="add__description" placeholder="Add description">
        <input type="number" class="add__value" placeholder="Value">
        <button class="add__btn"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="income">
        <h2 class="income__title">Income</h2>

        <div class="income__list">

          <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Salary</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 2,100.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Sold car</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 1,500.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->

        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="expenses">
        <h2 class="expenses__title">Expenses</h2>

        <div class="expenses__list">

          <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Apartment rent</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 900.00</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">21%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Grocery shopping</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 435.28</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">10%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OMG , that was such a silly mistake   >_<   THANKS A LOT  SIR! @Adam Azad

Answer (score 0):

You have problem 145 stroke word description

```
newItem = budgetCtrl.addItems(input.type, input.description, input.value);
```